# Swift String index advanceBy can't take int32

Tags: string, swift, indexing

```
let s : Int32 = 4 + var // var is Int32 somewhere else    
msg.substringToIndex(msg.startIndex.advancedBy(s)
```

Error code: Cannot invoke 'advancedBy' with an argument list of type '(Int32)'

I have tried with UInt32, it has the same kind of error

Comment: So coerce to Int. `advancedBy(Int(s))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
let s : Int32 = 4 + var
```

to

```
let s = Int(4 + var)
```